# Cannot mount my iPhone 6S+ in UBUNTU 16.04 LTS with iOS 11.0.2

Tags: iphone

I followed the instructions as described in an earlier Question.

I am getting the following error even when rebooting the device again and again ...

```
theo@theo-Vostro-V13:~$ usbmuxd
theo@theo-Vostro-V13:~$ idevicepair pair
SUCCESS: Paired with device 733449309a35dd721e1e1d6e305f3cb79a52893f
theo@theo-Vostro-V13:~$ ifuse /media/iPhone
Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.
```

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved; found this link:
https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc

The trick is to remove older packages first and to set the correct environment when building the new packages.