# Cannot mount iphone 6se to iphone with ios 11.4

Tags: mount, iphone

I have the same problem as the @tvkh53  who started [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963375/cannot-mount-my-iphone-6s-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-with-ios-11-0-2).

I'm running xenial 16.04, my iphone  6SE's ios is 11.4

When I run

```
idevicepair pair
```

I get

```
SUCCESS: Paired with device
```

But then

```
ifuse /media/iPhone
```

returns

```
Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.
```

The proposed solution is to follow the steps in [this link](https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc)

But the procedure suggested in the link is extremely intimidating, with the emphasis that it's not for the faint of heart.  I wasn't brave enought to proceed with it.   Is there a new solution to this problem that anybody knows of that is simpler?